# Change Style Values of ResourceDictionary at RunTime

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have defined a Font style common for all controls in a ResourceDictionary.

Now, the requirement is if user sets any other different Font from some application level configuration then all Controls should get that new Font properties/style.

I know ResourceDictionary can't have DataContext. But there can be hundreds of Fonts(so different Themes not possible), I am thinking if is there any way I can bind Font properties of ResourceDictionary to a Property which will take that new Font at runtime.
So Is there any other way to satisfy this in a Generic way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set new values for app.resources via code like this

```
app.Resources[name] = new FontFamily(value);
```

where app is your App (obviously) and can be set with `this` when your changing the Resource directly in the App.xaml.cs
`name` is your resource key as string, which could be e.g. `"fontFamily"`

```
<FontFamily x:Key="fontFamily">TheSansOsF</FontFamily>
```

You have to set the bindings for your font to dynamic resource, otherwise changing the font won´t work "on the fly"

```
<Setter Property="Label.FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource fontFamily}"></Setter>
```

EDIT: Furthermore when you try to use e.g. double as a resource you can use resources like this

```
<sys:Double x:Key="ctrlWidth">50</sys:Double>
```

and adding the sys to the application tag

```
<Application x:Class="Presenter.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. one more doubt. Its not only about font, it can also be color. so does same would work? and last line(<setter>) will be in ResourceDictionary right>

Comment: You can use pretty much all possible resources, you only have to figure out what the resource must be set to, e.g. for color it might be a SolidColorBrush you have to set via code. The fontFamily tag is from the <Application.Resources>, the setter is an example from a usercontrol you´re going to use the defined resource

Comment: Actually, I was hoping for something generic in ResourceDictionary. But I think I will have to go this way only.